# ASP.NET Core, Application Settings, and Security

Tags: json, security, web-config, asp.net-core, application-settings

In earlier versions of MVC/Web Api you put your settings in the web.config and you could somewhat assume the server would not serve up the web.config - things like your smtp settings and database connections.  If someone could get to those settings you typically had a much larger issue.

Now, in ASP.NET Core, you are putting your settings into json files, or using Environment variables - not necessarily an option if you are putting your site into a shared hosting solution where you can't access the OS.  This causes concern for me to be putting usernames, passwords, and connection strings into a json file.

1. Is there a possibility of the web server serving up your json files - especially if they are custom named and not just appsettings.json?  I'm just not sure if IIS protects these files like it did the web.config and can't seem to locate any postings on this topic.
2. Is there a better/recommended way to handle storage of things like username and password settings other than in plaintext in a json file - assuming that environment variables are not an option for you?
3. Is there no way to take advantage of the web.config in asp.net core for sensitive information?

Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Well your json files are not in the wwwroot folder so will never get served up.

Comment: As for encryption, try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets

Comment: Hey David, Thanks for the info.  I wasn't sure if even though it's not in the wwwroot folder it wouldn't be available.  I haven't looked at what the deployment looks like in the file system, so that's probably where I'd have my worry put to rest.  I read about the secrets manager before posting, but that's for dev only, and in upper environments it is replaced by environment variables - to which any developer using a shared hosting solution will likely not have access.